# Should I enable MSDTC in webserver or Database server when using "TransactionScope"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My question is related to this topic [TransactonScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979919/the-transaction-has-already-been-implicitly-or-explicitly-committed-or-aborted).
I have a web server and a database server and a remote database server.
I want to have a distributed transaction between local and remote server. I configured MSDTC for database servers and I can have a distributed transaction in Database servers with linked server.
but when I use `Transaction scope in system.transactions` name space I encounter following error when I Just open the second connection (Remote Connection).

```
error:
  The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted.
```

simplified code:

```
using (TransactionScope tscope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    //open connection db 1
    //insert into db1

    //open connection db2 (Remote databse) -- the problem is here
    //insert into db2

    tscope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable it since the runtime WHEN NECESSARY will escalate the transaction to use the Distributed Transaction Coordinator

Comment: How to enable it Run time? Please explain me more

Comment: Enable the MSDTC service, if you have not enabled it already. Also check that your network security settings are set up properly. Look at the section [Set the appropriate MSDTC Security Configuration options on Windows Server 2003 SP1, Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Vista] on this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924(v=bts.20).aspx

Comment: Should I enable MSDTC on My web server too? I enabled it for Local and remote Database servers?

Comment: I can ping remote database server with DNS Name and remote server can ping My local database server with Name too.